# How to combine multiple selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I select multiple fields in jQuery? (DOMs is an object)

```
clearFields: function() {
    $(DOMs.inpDes, DOMs.inpVal).val("");
    $(DOMs.inpDes).focus();
},
```

I use this

```
$(DOMs.inpDes, DOMs.inpVal).val("");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`add`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$(DOMs.inpDes).add(DOMs.inpVal).val("");
```

If these object properties are CSS selector strings, like ".myclass", then you can also concatenate them, like this:

```
$([DOMs.inpDes, DOMs.inpVal].join()).val("");
```

... or like this:

```
$(DOMs.inpDes + "," + DOMs.inpVal).val("");
```